# Creating different contexts with spring annotations

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-annotations, applicationcontext

I'm trying to understand a scenario which seems quite simple to me when using spring xml application context but seems more vague when using annotations.

Let's say I have a class that looks something like this (this is all for the sake of example. Don't pay attention to class names, etc...):

```
@Component
public class BusinessLogicImpl implements BusinessLogic {
    @Autowire
    BeanThatTalksWithDataSource beanThatTalksWithDataSource; 

    @Autowire
    BeanThatDoesSomeWork beanThatDoesSomeWork;

}
```

And then I have some other bean that uses this bean

```
 @Component
 public class MainLogicImpl implements MainLogic {

     @Autowire     
     BusinesLogic businessLogic;

 }
```

Let's assume that `BeanThatTalksWithDataSource` has 2 implementations - one that does work with file system data source, and another that works with DB. Also the `BeanThatDoesSomeWork` has 2 different implementations.

I want to create 4 different configurations that involves each combination of the 2 implementations of `BeanThatTalksWithDataSource` with the 2 implementations of `BeanThatDoesSomeWork` and at the end to load the correct variant to the `MainLogicImpl`.

In xml it's fairly easy - I create 4 xml files that hold the 4 different possible contexts. What would be the equivalent of such thing when working with annotations?

**I would like to emphasise that I'm talking about annotation and not @Configuration class. I'm trying to figure out if that's possible with annotations alone.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate all the implementations with `@Profile` and when starting your application set the active profiles. Now when component-scanning kicks in it will only pickup the beans which satisfy the active profiles.

Links

@Profile ([javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html))

Answer (score 1):

You can place different implementations in 4 different packages and choose different packages for component scan.